# Mysql Trigger creation query - Syntax error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am getting an error in my mySql query when i execute my create trigger query in mysql using phpmyadmin which is provided below.

**Error:**

[image]

Error Message :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

**MySql Query:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_INSERT_club_app_member_contact_info After INSERT ON club_app_member_contact_info
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO club_app_events_list(type_id,event_title,event_description,event_date,event_time,event_venue)
              values(1,CONCAT('Happy Birthday ',NEW.title,NEW.name),NEW.mobile_no,NEW.dob,'8.30AM','');
  IF NEW.ismarried == 'Yes' THEN
          INSERT INTO club_app_events_list(type_id,event_title,event_description,event_date,event_time,event_venue)
                      values(1,CONCAT('Happy Birthday ',NEW.title_for_spouse,NEW.nameOf_spouse,'Spouse of (',NEW.title,NEW.name,')'),NEW.spouse_mobileNo,NEW.spouse_dob,'8.30AM','');
          INSERT INTO club_app_events_list(type_id,event_title,event_description,event_date,event_time,event_venue)
                      values(2,CONCAT('Happy Wedding Anniversary to ',NEW.title,NEW.name ,' & ',NEW.title_for_spouse,NEW.nameOf_spouse),NEW.mobile_no,NEW.weeding_date,'8.30AM','');      
  END IF
END
```

I don't know what's wrong with my query.Can anyone help me to find a solution.

Comment: few thing i noticed `IF NEW.ismarried == 'Yes' THEN` it should `IF NEW.ismarried = 'Yes' THEN BEGIN` and `END IF` should end with  semicolon `;` although BEGIN end enclose `END;`

Comment: But still it is not working

Comment: if you are using phpmyadmin then please use `//` Delimiter for pl/sql functions, procedures or triggers. rest all looking fine

Comment: @Girish How can i do that.? Because i am new to mysql It would be better if you show an example.

Comment: ok, please see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4Qk7.png

Comment: Still not working.!

Comment: is there still same error?

Comment: Yes it's worked but one correction is there. No need of any delimiter.Any way thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Great, you would using >=5.6 mysql server version, Although this is only phpmyadmin analysis warnings not a mysql server response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few thing i noticed `IF NEW.ismarried == 'Yes' THEN` it should `IF NEW.ismarried = 'Yes' THEN` `BEGIN` and `END IF` should end with semicolon `;` although `BEGIN` end enclose `END;`

But since i am trying to execute this query using phpmyadmin I have to remove Delimiter from the bottom text box of phpmyadmin.
But note that this is only phpmyadmin analysis warnings not a mysql server response.